Exactly what changes does AADLoginForLinux make to your OS configuration when it installs?
Microsoft tell us that we can enable the AADLoginForLinux extension on an Azure Linux VM, and it will allow you to ssh login with AAD MFA (provided you use their own ssh client of course, as it requires an 'extension' to ssh protocol)
However, exactly what changes are made to the Linux OS configuration to achieve this? There seems to be no documentation of this, and our system is not working for AAD login.
So far, I can see that it

Adds 'aad' as an option in nsswitch.conf to manage users and groups
Adds pam_aad.so module to your PAM system-auth and password-auth, in the 'auth' and 'sesion' as a 'required' module
Requires outbound connection via https to a number of microsoft sites (presumably to verify tokens passed by 'az ssh')
Possibly other changes to sshd_config?

Logs seem to go into /var/log/security but they are pretty basic.
Can anyone provide a definitive list of the configuration changes made/required by this extension?
